# Как вывести все машины через wialon js api?

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести все метки (машины докторов) на карту по токену, по примеру: 
https://sdk.wialon.com/playground/pj6Fn0Fy/1 
С виалоном раньше вообще не работал, поэтому для меня он на какой то магии работает :З

Если нужна будет информация, дополню вопрос.
Делаю так и ничего, подскажите как можно сделать вывод на карту всех меток?

```js
    // Получаем докторов
    queryFunc("/wo/doclist/").then((dataRes) => {
        console.log("test", dataRes);
        let units = wialon.core.Session.getInstance().getItem(dataRes.wialon_id);
        if(!units) return;
        let pos = units.getPosition();
        if(!pos) return;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибочка, wialon только предоставляет информацию о машинах, для отображения они используют leaflet.js.
Вывод всех объектов:

```js
    // Промисифицированный ajax который возвращает докторов
    queryFunc("/wo/doclist/").then(function(dataRes) {
        console.log(`Тест: \n ${dataRes}`);

        // В dataRes приходит id виалона(wialon_id)
        $.each(dataRes, (key, val1) => {
            console.log(val1.wialon_id);
            let val = Number(val1.wialon_id);
            var unit = wialon.core.Session.getInstance().getItem(val); // get unit by id
            if(!unit) return; // exit if no unit
            var pos = unit.getPosition(); // get unit position
            if(!pos) return; // exit if no position

            if (map) { // check if map created
                var icon = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: unit.getIconUrl(32)
                });
                marker = L.marker({lat: pos.y, lng: pos.x}, {icon: icon}).addTo(map);
            };
        });
```